# how can there be missing values in an IDENTITY(1,1) colimn

Tags: sql-server, identity

In an existing application there is a User_Log table, with a sequential ID column.

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

However on checking the table I find there are 16,874 missing IDs in that 1.3M row table.

When inserting a row into this table, at what point is the next ID value assigned ?
Is the ID incremented, but no data written, if an OnInsert trigger fails ?
What other kind of error could cause no row to be written, but the ID incremented ?

This query reveals the missing IDs.

```
WITH Missing (miss_ID, maxid)
AS
(
 SELECT 1 AS miss_ID, (select max(id) from user_log)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT miss_ID + 1, maxid FROM Missing
 WHERE miss_ID < maxid
)
SELECT miss_ID
FROM Missing
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_log UL on UL.id = Missing.miss_ID
WHERE UL.id is NULL
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```

I'm trying to rule out deletion of records in the user activity log, that would be a bad thing.

Thanks for all assistance on this.

Comment: Take a peek at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106209/unexpected-gaps-in-identity-column

Comment: If you want to prevent users from deleting records from a table, don't grant them direct access.  Restrict table editing to stored procedures.  You can also use a `Trigger` to audit (or prevent, if I'm not mistaken) deletes from that table.  I realize this may be a case of "closing the barn door after the horses have escaped", but it would be good practice moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

> When inserting a row into this table, at what point is the next ID value assigned ?

The value is generated before the insert.  And it's non-transactional, in that other sessions can immediately generate successive values without waiting to see if the insert ultimately succeeds and is committed.

> Is the ID incremented, but no data written, if an OnInsert trigger fails?

Yes.

> What other kind of error could cause no row to be written, but the ID incremented ?

Any failure or rollback of a transaction containing inserts into the table will leave gaps in the IDENTITY values.  Also SQL Server caches blocks of generated identity values by default, and a failure of the SQL Server process will leave gaps, typically of about 1000 values.

Comment: John, David, thank you.

So to check for possible deletions, we should use another method.

Comment: Yes @PAulMaskens … most likely a table to log delete requests and an after-delete trigger to populate it.